# put array to textboxes, array is smaller than number of textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I have one array of 8 text boxes and one of 2:

```
    Dim arrA() As TextBox = {a1, a2} 'names of people
    Dim arrB() As TextBox = {b1, b2, b3, b4,b5,b6,b7,b8 } 'output textboxes
```

I want my 8 output text boxes **arrB()** filled with the names of people from **arraA()** in a loop.

In this case all names will be visible 4 times in **arrB** on form:

name1
name2
name1
name2
name1
name2
name1
name2

Comment: do you just want each item in the array to go to eight different textboxes of  each item?

Comment: thx  Werdna, basically i want to fill my arrB with arrA until all textboxes of arrB are filled. so if arrA would consist of 3 items, the output of arrB would be: name1, name2, name 3, name1, name2 ,name 3, name 1, name 2 (end, all 8 textboxes of arrB are filled now).  I want to use a loop, no hardcoding, cause in the future, these 8 textboxes will expand to about 48 ;-)

Comment: What do you want to assign to what? The Text of the arrA into the Text of arrB boxes or the Name?

Comment: You should post what you tried.

Comment: hi Uno, peolpe will enter 2 names into arrA. so, The Text of the arrA will be visible  into the Text of arrB boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily solve it with the **Mod** operator:

```
Dim index = 0

For Each output In arrB
    output.Text = arrA(index Mod arrA.Count).Text
    index++
Next
```

Or

```
For index = 0 To arrB.Count - 1
    arrB(index).Text = arrA(index Mod arrA.Count).Text
Next
```

Comment: @erik Glad it helped :), please accept the answer if it solved your problem.